# am new with symfony and i need some advices

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I have a problem regarding a Symfony application, I want to take as input the "username" or "id" for my controller , and receive information that is in my table "user" and also 2 other table for example : A user has one or more levels , and also it has points must earn points to unlock a level , I want my dan Home page display the username and the level and extent that it has , I jn am beginner and not come to understand the books symfony that I use, I work with PARALLEL " symfony_book " and " symfony_cook_book " and also tutorial youtube May I blocks , here is the code for my cotroler 
"

```
/**  
* @Route("/{id}")      
* @Template()      
* @param $id=0      
* @return array      
*/     
public function getUserAction($id)     
{          
     $username = $this->getDoctrine()             
         ->getRepository('voltaireGeneralBundle:FosUser')              
         ->find($id);         
     if (!$username) {             
         throw $this->createNotFoundException('No user found for id '.$id);
     }         
     //return ['id' => $id,'username' => $username];         
     return array('username' => $username);              
}
```

and I have to use the relationship among classes

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
class Experience {      
    /**      
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FosUser", mappedBy="experience")      
    */     
    protected $fosUsers;

    public function __construct()     
    {
        $this->fosUsers = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

and

```
class FosUser {      
    /**      
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Experience", inversedBy="fosUsers")      
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="experience_id", referencedColumnName="id")      
    */     
    protected $fosUsers;   
}
```

and i have always an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony you cannot return an array in Action function!, Action function must always return a Response object...So if you want to return data to browser in Symfony, Action function have to return a string wrapped up in Response object.
In your controller code, to return the array to browser, You can serialize an array to JSON and send it back to browser:

```
public function getUserAction($id)     
{          
     $username = $this->getDoctrine()             
         ->getRepository('voltaireGeneralBundle:FosUser')              
         ->find($id);         
     if (!$username) {             
         throw $this->createNotFoundException('No user found for id '.$id);
     }                  
     return new Response(json_encode(array('username' => $username)));              
}
```

I suggest you to read more about HTTP protocol , PHP, and Symfony.